# Connect to Running Program via COM - Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject

Tags: c#, .net-core, com, marshalling, com-interop

I am using a software package that offers an "extension" package, largely undocumented, that allows for creation of extensions that allow automation within the program. It's a COM interface between the addin/extension and the running software.

I have a need to connect and run the automation from outside the software, while the software is running.

The limited sample code shows a method that must be crearted that is called by the software when the addin is executed from the software:

```cs
 AppComExtensionWrapper m_wrapper;
 const int S_FALSE = 1;

 public int AppConnect(object unknown)
 {
     try
     {
         IntPtr p = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(unknown);
         return m_wrapper.AppComConnect(p);
     }
     catch
     {
         return S_FALSE;
     }
 }
```

When the extension is called from within the app, it calls the `AppConnect` method and passes the `unknown` object.

**When running externally, how do I get the `unknown` object and connect to my app? Or is there another method to connect to the app?**

I have tried looking through `System.Diagnostics` to get the running process but not sure how to get that to connect. I am somewhat stuck.

Comment: GetIUnknownForObject is just a method that gets the IUnknown native pointer from a .NET object that supports COM (every COM object has an IUnknown pointer). If by "externally" you means out-of-process, nothing indicates that it's technically possible. What's probably possible is add your addin in-process and talk with your external application using any inter-process-communication mean (tcp/grpc/http, etc.) or even another COM channel of yours that would work out-of-process https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications

Comment: @SimonMourier is it possible to get the pointer of the app from out of process?

Comment: What form has "the pointer of the app"? What is it? If it's not a COM interface reference, no. If it's a COM interface reference, only if it was designed to work out-of-process (ie: means no in general).